# Holomorphic curves invariant by lattices

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Suppose I have an entire function $f : \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ for 
$n \geq 1$.

Let $C$ be the curve $f(\mathbb{C})$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (free $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of rank $2n$) and assume that $\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$ is algebraic - it is an abelian variety.

Suppose that $C$ is stable by $\Lambda$ i.e. $C + \lambda = C$ for
all $\lambda$ in $\Lambda$.

What conditions that imposes on $f$? I think it should impose that $f$ is a linear function but I have no proof.

This question is probably trivial to an expert in complex analysis..

Comment: If $n \geq 2$, there is in general no such a function. Indeed, the $\Lambda$-invariant curve $C$ would give rise to a compact $1$-dimensional submanifold in the complex torus $T = \mathbb{C}^n / \Lambda$, but it is known that for a general choice of the lattice such a torus contains no $1$-dimensional complex submanifolds at all.
So, your lattice must be special. For instance, you can require that the torus $T$ is algebraic (i.e, an abelian variety), which means that $\Lambda$ satisfies the Riemann bilinear conditions.

Comment: Thanks for this reply! Yes, in fact I forgot to mention - my torus IS algebraic, it is an abelian variety

Comment: For $n=1$, all your condition $C + \lambda = C$ does is tell you that $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is surjective. (If it weren't surjective, then it would have to miss a lattice of values, and so, by big Picard, it would have to be constant, which is clearly incompatible with $C + \lambda = C$.) There are many, many such surjective holomorphic maps (for example, all of the non constant polynomials); they need not be linear.

Comment: Thanks for this; what about n>1?

Comment: Well, $n>1$ is still going to have this problem because if $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^n$ does actually satisfy your condition, then $f\circ h:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^n$ will also satisfy your condition for any $h:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ that is surjective.  By the way, for $n>1$, there is no linear $f$ that satisfies your assumptions because you can always arrange that $f(0)=0$, and then your condition would imply that the complex line $f(\mathbb{C})$ contains the generators of the lattice $\Lambda$, which is impossible for $n>1$.

Comment: It seems that $f(\mathbb{C})$ has to be a linear subspace - by a theorem of Bloch the Zariski closure of   the image of $f(\mathbb{C})$ in $A=\mathbb{C}^n/Lambda$ is a translate of an abelian subvariety, so if $f(\mathbb{C})$ is $\Lambda$-periodic, then its image in $A$ is closed hence algebraic hence a translate of an abelian subvariety and hence $f(\mathbb{C})$ is a linear subspace. I guess my question was whether one can prove this directly without appealing to Bloch's theorem... At least can one prove easily that a $\Lambda$-periodic $f(\mathbb{C})$ is an algebraic curve?

Comment: I don't see how you are concluding that the image of $f$ in $A$ is closed.  Why couldn't it be that the closure of $f(\mathbb{C})$ in $A$ is all of $A$?

Comment: Actually, I still think that in that case $\pi f(\mathbb{C})$ has to be closed (where $\pi$ is the projection from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $A$). Fix a compact funfamental set $F$ for $\Lambda$. Let $z$ in $f(\mathbb{C})$, write it as $z = z_F + \lambda$ with $\lambda \in \Lambda$. As $f(\mathbb{C}) = f(\mathbb{C}) + \Lambda$, $z_F \in f(\mathbb{C})$ hence $\pi(f(\mathbb{C})) = \pi(f(\mathbb{C}) \cap F))$ hence closed.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being silly, but you seem to be assuming implicitly that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is closed. This seems like it does not have to be true, for instance, $n=2$ and $f(z)=\{e^{iz},e^{iz^2}\}$.